# How would i draw a Graph like that with LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, xetex, graphs

I want to create a Graph like this for my Document. I know how to create a Graph with pgfplots and tikz, but how would I create these arrows and their explanations *iteration x*

This is where it is from: https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-fundamentals-via-linear-regression-41a5d11f5220

[image: Graph from https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-fundamentals-via-linear-regression-41a5d11f5220]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: the data or a MWE that looks like the graph without the arrow would be a starting point for someone to help you.

Comment: Do you want someone to make that chart for you?
A tip, learn, try and fail, before asking for help.

Comment: I tried to do so and the Graph itself is eas.. I just dont know how to create these arrows

Comment: Then please post the code that you have so far (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). Whoever wants to help you, can copy your code and extend it. Just click on the `edit` button left below your question, paste your code, and format  it as code (mark the code lines and click on the '{}' button of the edit windows).

Answer (score 3):

This is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={F(\x,\a,\b,\c)=\a*exp(-(\x-\b)*(\x-\b)/\c);
    f(\x)=5-F(\x,4.5,2.8,6);},bullet/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt},
    font=\sffamily]
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,6) node[below left]{$f(x)$} |- (6,0) node[below left]{$x$};
 \draw plot[smooth,domain=0:5] (\x,{f(\x)});
 \foreach \X [count=\Y]
    in {0.2,0.5,0.9,1.2,1.8,2,2.2,2.6,2.8}
    {\draw (\X,-0.2) -- (\X,0.2);
     \ifnum\Y=1
      \path (\X,{f(\X)}) node[bullet] (b\Y){};
     \else
     \draw[very thin,gray,-{Latex[bend,length=2pt,width=2pt]}] (b\the\numexpr\Y-1) 
        to[bend left] (\X,{f(\X)}) node[bullet] (b\Y){};
     \fi};
 \draw[stealth-] (b1) -- ++ (60:1) node[above]{Start};
 \foreach \Y in {2,3}
 {\path (b\Y) to[bend left] node[above right]{Iteration \Y} (b\the\numexpr\Y+1);}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!